# why magento 1.8 discount missing

Tags: upgrade, ce-1.6.2.0, cart-rule, ce-1.8.0.0

we update from magento 1.7.0.2 to magento 1.8.0.0 and are missing all cart rules discounts. We have full price without discount only. We are stuck and dont understand why.

Answer (score 3):

Catalog rules are applied by cron every day for current day. In CatalogRule extension cron is set to 1:00 am. 
But in 1.8 this task is sheduled some hours earlier (depending on your time zone). I have not found reason for this now, but you can to chage cron start later in file

```
/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/etc/config.xml
```

from

```
<cron_expr>0 1 * * *</cron_expr>
```

to

```
<cron_expr>0 3 * * *</cron_expr>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug/feature in 1.8, Catalog Rules work with conditions for attributes with scope other than Global. Took me days to figure it out. Hope it helps.